# TypeError: Cannot find function setvalue in object Range

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I have this script that picks the last updated row from google sheet and successfully posts it to the project's system via external API.

Now I added a few lines of code so that it updates fetch success or failure on a last cell of the row it picked data from, but I keep getting Cannot find function set value in object Range. I am pretty new to javascript so, I will appreciate any assistance.

Here is the code without the auth key.

```
function lastRowData(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() 
 var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()
 var lastRowData = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastCol).getValues()
 return lastRowData[0]
}
function myFunction() {
var lastRow = lastRowData()
var data = {

    'name':lastRow[2],
    'client': lastRow[3],
    'starts_at':lastRow[5],
    'ends_at':lastRow[6],
    'project_state':lastRow[4],
};
    var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'payload': payload,
        'muteHttpExceptions': true
    };
        var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/projects?auth=**token**';
       enter code here var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
        if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) { 
        sheet.getRange("X1").setvalue("Yes");
    }
    else {
        sheet.getRange("X1").setvalue("No");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.setValue()` not `.setvalue()`, case is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.setValue()` instead of `.setvalue()`.